# Phase portrait of a nonlinear system numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to plot phase portrait of a nonlinear system using numpy but 
`odeint` gives me following warnings and print unrial plot.

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
>     warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
>
> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
>     x2_d = x1 - 4 * 1/np.tan(x1 + x2)
>
> ODEintWarning: Illegal input detected (internal error). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
>     warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)

As I understand this is happens because in some conditions value of `np.tan() = 0`. How can I overcam this and get more more accurate plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def nonlinear(state, t):
    # unpack the state vector
    x1 = state[0]
    x2 = state[1]

    # compute state derivatives
    x1_d = x2
    x2_d = x1 - 4 * 1/np.tan(x1 + x2)

    # return the state derivatives
    return [x1_d, x2_d]


def generate_initial_states(start, stop, step):
    states = []
    for i in np.arange(start, stop, step):
        states.append([i, i])
        states.append([i, -i])
    return states


t = np.linspace(0.0, 20, 1000)
initial_states = generate_initial_states(-1.0, 1.0, 0.2)


outputs = []
for state in initial_states:
    outputs.append(odeint(nonlinear, state, t))

fig = plt.figure()
for output in outputs:
    plt.plot(output[:, 0], output[:, 1], 'r-')

plt.xlabel('x_1')
plt.ylabel('x_2')
plt.title('phase portrait')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Calculate the denominator `t = tan(x1 + x2)` first, make a mask `m = t != 0` then  create an empty `x2_d` and fill it using the mask: `x2_d[m] = x1[m] - 4 * 1/t[m]` and `x2_d[~m] = -numpy.inf`or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, It solves problem with divide by zero, but odeint still generate warning ** ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)** and phase portrait look unrial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system has a singularity, that indeed shows up in the numerical evaluation.

A physically sound solution is to *not* start the trajectories on the line `x1 + x2 = 0`. This is however exactly what you are doing by adding as starting points `[i, -i]`. You can add other regions of phase space instead, like a regularly spaced grid (but avoiding `x1=-x2`).

Comment: Yes, you absolutily right. Now i generate `initial_conditions` without `[i, -i]` from 0.1 to 1 with step 0.1. This solve problem with divide by zero. But following problem still exist **ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)** and phase protrait still look awful.